# Ad-Gallery Loader.gif not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this image gallery http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/ but I am having trouble.
the loader.gif image is not showing up at all in IE9 just a red x. I am a newbie to javascript, this is at the top of the javascript file

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.adGallery = function(options) {
    var defaults = { loader_image: 'loader.gif',
```

the image is in the same directory as this javascript file so the path is ok.. also there is no mention of this loader.gif in the css file at all.

this is the my site, www.kayleighwhite.org/black_white.html

Answer (score 0):

the path ok?
have you ever tried chrome developer tools?
here's the screenshoot
[image]

[image]

as you can see there are some 404 status

Comment: no I have not tried it, I will though. but I know that somewhere the path is not correct, but more or less where? or where should it be defined, there is nothing in the html or css, so it must be in the javascript?

Comment: loader.gif url is at http://www.kayleighwhite.org/img/loader.gif for quick fix, you can move loader.gif to the folder, or you can try to re-implement ad-gallery

Comment: the url is kayleighwhite.org/gallery/loader.gif

Comment: but the browser request loader.gif at http://www.kayleighwhite.org/img/loader.gif you can see from chrome developer tools too.

Comment: ok so I see it in the tools element tab, but wow I can not find that rule in my css at all? I can see it is pointing to a folder that is not there but, where is that rule defined? I can not find it in jquery.ad-gallery.css and that does not even show up in the html either....

Comment: ok I found it it was defined on line 245 of the js file. thank you for your help!

Comment: so its in jquery.ad-gallery.js, it's the default loader.gif path, cause you don't define it. to manually define your loader.gif try this

`var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
      loader_image: 'http://kayleighwhite.org/gallery/loader.gif'
});`

Answer (score 0):

Usually the file doesn't exist in the location the link is pointing to

`loader_image: 'loader.gif'` means it is looking for the file in the top level of the site. So `www.kayleighwhite.org/loader.gif`.

There is also an error looking for the file at `http://www.kayleighwhite.org/img/loader.gif`

Use Google Chrome. Right click > inspect element, have a look around

Answer (score 0):

open jquery.ad-gallery.js and add the absolute path of the loader.gif file. Eg:

**`var defaults = { loader_image: 'http://your_domain.com/ad_gallery/lib/loader.gif',`**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacking the jquery.ad-gallery.js, specify the image location under options:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.adGallery = function(options) {
        var defaults = { loader_image: 'location/to/the/image/loader.gif',
```